# Refresh Token and Access Token With Azure Entra ID and Microsoft Graph

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, refresh-token, azure-entra-id

I am using `Azure Entra Id` for authentication and `Microsoft Graph Api` token acquiring. When I'm logging-in I'm only receiving `access token` which I'm then saving in local storage.

Can someone guide me how can I get `refresh token` along with it and then how would I use that refresh token to acquire new access token automatically. What will be the flow for acquiring mew access token and whats the best workflow in which a refresh token is used to get new access token?

Furthermore, whats best place to store token `session storage` or `local storage`?

My frontend is on react and backend is on asp.net core web apis, login logic is implemented on react side.

```
const handleRedirect = async () => {
  let auth = await instance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(auth));
  localStorage.setItem("access_token", auth.accessToken);
};
```

Comment: adding `offline_access` into the `scope` when obtaining the access token will make you get refresh token at the same time. and I don't know the answer for other questions